# Adding link text to generated new links with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Newbie to SO...Basically, I have a table of links, and within that table I'm trying to use jquery to append an additional link below existing text within a table cell. I've almost got it, but I'm having an issue trying to figure out how to only have the link text from within each cell individually populate, rather than each link get stuffed into a single created link. To illustrate, here's my generic code:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Building1</a><br />
555 Main st.<br />
Anytown, USA 02767<br />
(555) 555-5555
    </td>
    <td>Placeholder text</td>
    <td>Placeholder text</td>
    <td>Placeholder text</td>
    <td>Placeholder text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Building2</a><br />
556 Main st.<br />
Anytown, USA 02767<br />
(555) 555-5556
    </td>
    <td>Placeholder text</td>
    <td>Placeholder text</td>
    <td>Placeholder text</td>
    <td>Placeholder text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Building3</a><br />
557 Main st.<br />
Anytown, USA 02767<br />
(555) 555-5557
    </td>
    <td>Placeholder text</td>
    <td>Placeholder text</td>
    <td>Placeholder text</td>
    <td>Placeholder text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And then here is my jquery:

```
var test1 = $('table tr td:first-child:contains(",") a').text();
$('table tr td:first-child:contains(",")').append('<br /><a href="https://www.moreinfo.com/search?find_desc=' + test1 + '&find_loc=blahblah">Link</a>');
```

I've tried a variety of things, and assume there needs to be an .each involved someplace, but more experienced help would be appreciated. Here's a fiddle that I created that might make it a little clearer -- https://jsfiddle.net/roz2uL4e/.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by each link getting stuffed into a single created link? Is your JSfiddle sample the way you want it to look in the end?

Comment: We would be able to answer better if we had a clearer idea of the challenge you are facing. Are you trying to find out how to loop through all cells in the table?

Comment: Per my fiddle, I'm basically trying (where it says in the code "find_desc="), where it currently resolves to "find_desc=building1building2building3", I want it to be "find_desc=building1", and then in the next row "find_desc=building2", and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over your cells using `.each()` method:

```
$('table tr td:first-child:contains(",")').each(
  function(){
    var test1 = $(this).find("a").text();
    $(this).append('<br /><a href="https://www.moreinfo.com/search?find_desc=' + test1 + '&find_loc=blahblah">Link</a>');
  }
);
```

Comment: That was it alright...I knew it had something to do with iterating with each but for the life of me I could not get all the pieces working together! Thanks very much for the help Brahma.